# configure users using opensips 1.11(Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: sip, voip, ubuntu-14.04, opensips

After installing opensips(It will be better if i won't have to use opensips control panel) how can add users and can make test call.

Note:
I am a newbie, and following this guide for installation.

http://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Install-CompileAndInstall-1-11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the *Control Panel*, you can use *opensipsctl* in order to add new subscribers. All you need to do is:

```
opensipsctl add liviu@opensips.org mypassword
```

For more help on the *opensipsctl*, simply type:

```
opensipsctl
```

Comment: thanks a lot. May i have some links so i can learn opensips core so in future i can contribute to opensips ?

Comment: A complete and useful collection of information about scripting, modules and core is the [Manual](http://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Tutorials-GettingStarted). Then there are some advanced [tutorials](http://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Tutorials), along with the [development ones](http://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Development-Tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

For any user that's trying to install the package under Ubuntu by instructions from official manual, please make sure that you also read setup manual from github page, section [C] and [D]

> https://github.com/OpenSIPS/opensips/blob/master/INSTALL

I've tried to do a fresh setup of opensips on a virtual machine to test the functions. The provided packages on Jessie branch of Debian (which is supported by Ubuntu 14.04) is not included MySQL database deployment.

For a quick test I'm using the DBText as DB engine, and using command to add user will not succeed. Because the DBText engine requires email field, however the opensipsctl interface doesn't understand, so we should add some subscribers by adding some lines to Subscriber table, basically is located under path **/usr/local/etc/opensips/dbtext**, e.g:

> 1:brian:192.168.186.129:password:123456:xxx:xxx:xxx
>   2:julia:192.168.186.129:password:123456:xxx:xxx:xxx

Example above using the ip which is the virtual machine ip.

Good luck.